# потеря значения в классе

Tags: javascript, классы

есть класс

```
  constructor(selector, {formSubmit}) {
    super(selector); //наследование
    this._formSubmit = formSubmit; //колбек функция
    this._form = this._popup.querySelector('.form'); //поиск формы в попап
    this._submit = this._submit.bind(this); //присвание сабмиту this
  }

  //риватный метод поведения собмита
   _submit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.id)
     console.log('_submit');
    //при сабмите надо удалять карточку по в колбек передаем параметр id карточки
     this._formSubmit(this.id);
  }

  //метод открытия
  open(id) {
    //на форму вешаем слушатель
    this._form.addEventListener('submit', this._submit)
    //наследуем открытие
    super.open();
  }
}
```

на вход получает значение но при событии в метод _submit уже попадает undefined
в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //метод открытия
  open(id) {
    //на форму вешаем слушатель
       this.id = id
    this._form.addEventListener('submit', this._submit)
    //наследуем открытие
    super.open();
  }
```

и потеря исчезает передается все как надо.